# Is it possible to set ag-grid column as fixed so that it could not be moved?

Tags: grouping, ag-grid

Is it possible /how to fix grouping column so that it could not be moved?

[image]

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/grouping/

Answer (score 3):

Pin your column to the left and set `lockPinned` to true, both in `autoGroupColumnDef`:

```
autoGroupColumnDef: {
    pinned: 'left',
    lockPinned: true,
  },
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/0U8kjgBU4jScBle5).

Comment: Hi @Agnes if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.